# Upload file with Meteor and React-Dropzone

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, image-uploading

I'm trying upload images to meteor collection using react-dropzone:

Meteor packages using: `meteor add jalik:ufs` and `meteor add jalik:ufs-gridfs`

`imports/api/images`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { UploadFS } from 'meteor/jalik:ufs';

export const Images = new Mongo.Collection('images');
export const Thumbs = new Mongo.Collection('thumbs');

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('thumbs', function(id) {
        return Thumbs.find({
            originalStore: 'images',
            originalId: {
                $in: ids
            }
        });
    })

    Meteor.publish('images', function() {
        return Images.find({});
    })
}

function loggedIn(userId) {
  return !!userId;
}

export const ThumbsStore = new UploadFS.store.GridFS({
  collection: Thumbs,
  name: 'thumbs',
  permissions: new UploadFS.StorePermissions({
    insert: loggedIn,
    update: loggedIn,
    remove: loggedIn
  }),
  transformWrite(from, to, fileId, file) {
    // Resize to 32x32
    const gm = require('gm');

    gm(from, file.name)
      .resize(32, 32)
      .gravity('Center')
      .extent(32, 32)
      .quality(75)
      .stream()
      .pipe(to);
  }
});

export const ImagesStore = new UploadFS.store.GridFS({
    collection: Images,
    name: 'images',
    permissions: new UploadFS.StorePermissions({
        insert: loggedIn,
        update: loggedIn,
        remove: loggedIn
    }),
    filter: new UploadFS.Filter({
        contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }),
    copyTo: [
        ThumbsStore
    ]
});

Meteor.methods({
    upload: function(file) {
        const photo = {
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type,
            size: file.size
        };

        const upload = new UploadFS.Uploader({
            data: file,
            file: photo,
            store: ImagesStore,
            onError: () => {
                console.log('error');
            },
            onComplete: console.log('Completed'),
        });

        upload.start();
    }
})
```

And in my component which is using react-dropzone:

```
onDrop(file) {
        UploadFS.selectFile(() => {
            Meteor.call('upload', file)
        })
    }
```

But when I try to drop a file into it, it shows nothing, and after I checked the mongo command, there's no images and thumbs collections at all even thought I imported it to the main.js file on server, it's not being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDrop will return a list of files, not a single file.